# Null-checking and handling within LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, list, null

**Edit:** Solution ended up just being null-checking. Check top answer for solution.

I'll be concise with this one.

`Layers` is a list of `TestNineGridData`. `TestNineGridData` has a property `VectorSource` which has property `Paths`, which is also a list.

`Paths` is a list of `NineGridPath` objects, each of which has a `Height` and `Width` property.

I need to find the maximum `NineGridPath` `Height` and `Width` in `Layers`.

This is what I am currently getting but I am getting a `NullReferenceException`.

```
int maxHeightInLayers = (int)Layers.Max(x => x.VectorSource.Paths.Max(y => y.Height));
int maxWidthInLayers = (int)Layers.Max(x => x.VectorSource.Paths.Max(y => y.Width));
```

I suspect the issue may be in my inner lambda expression since it could be checking for a `Height` property in `Paths`, but I'm not sure how to resolve this.

Note: For clarification, since it could be vague in my wording, VectorSource does not need to be iterated over. `VectorSource` has the property `Paths`, not its list elements.

Comment: are you sure all of your VectorSouces and Paths are _not null_ ?

Comment: It's possible! I was so caught up in my fancy LINQ being correct I skipped an obvious error. Although, just from working for such a long time with this application, I doubt that VectorSource or Paths is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding some null-checks to your query:

```
int maxHeightInLayers = (int) Layers
            .Max(x => (x.VectorSource != null && x.VectorSource.Paths != null)
                ? x.VectorSource.Paths.Where(p => p != null).Max(y => y.Height)
                : 0);
```